# Сделать поочередный вывод комментария пользователя

Tags: php, post, form

При выполнении данного скрипта

```
<?php

$name = $_POST ['user'];
$comment = $_POST ['comment'];
$str = ":";
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){

    $s = $_POST['namepost'] . $name . ":" . "<br />";

        }
 for ($j = 0; $j < count($comment); $j++){

    $st = $_POST['namepost2'] . $comment . "<br />";

        }
?>

<form name="someform" method="post">
  <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
   <input type="text" size="40" name="user">
   <input type="hidden" name="namepost" value="<?=$s?>"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="namepost2" value="<?=$st?>">  
  </p>
 <p><b><?=$s?></b><?=$st?></p>
   <p><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3" placeholder="Введите комментарий"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```

если ввести например пару комментариев соответствующих пользователей, над полем ввода комментария выводится такая картина:

Я:

Он:

аааа

юююю

А нужно чтобы выводилось поочередно:

Я:аааа

Он:юююю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST ['user'];
$comment = $_POST ['comment'];
$str = ":";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){
    $s = $_POST['namepost'] . $name . ": " . $_POST['namepost2'] . $comment . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Yaroslav. Это работает!